# How to reference individual cells in Excel to variable data from records in an external SQL table

Tags: microsoft-excel, odbc

I have a SQL table containing date oriented financial data eg. multiple daily records with fields for Date, Account code and Value. I want to set up dynamic links (formulas) from cells in an Excel speadsheet to this data so when the spreadsheet is loaded the data is fetched from all the relevant records. The spreadsheet has the Account codes on the x axis and Dates on the y. Each day the SQL table has new data in it for the new day and I want the spreadsheet to reference this new data for the column for the new day.

Any ideas? I have seen how you can generally bring in data from a SQL table (in our case using ODBC as it is not MS SQL) but the data is not simply bringing in multiple records as you would a CVS file but specific records in the SQL table referencing to specific cells and columns in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

several ways to approach this. One is to create a Excel / SQL data connection link and connect your tables in a format you wish to receive. The Data tool will allow you flexibility in choosing format etc.

Another way is to write UDF in VBA that can be called for each row / column combinations individually once you have the ODBC connection set up in code.

One more way (and an extension of the earlier method) is to write a macro that refreshes the entire dataset in excel (or appends existing data; depending on how you program it).

Comment: Thank you. With the first method is it possible to address individual cells to particular fields and records in the SQL data as a formula so for example the date would be a variable (as it is the date which changes each day)?

Comment: when you use data connections (Excel / SQL), the output will be a XY matrix with m-rows by n-columns. you may not be able to force destinations (say, 3 columns of data followed by 2 blanks and then 3 more columns of data). To achieve that, you would have to follow the second or third approach.